# Add array element to smarty variable in PrestaShop 1.7 Theme

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

When modifying my theme, I want to make a change to this template file

`themes/my_theme/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/Category.tpl`

Contents of the original file:

```
{block name='category_miniature_item'}
  <section class="category-miniature">
    <a href="{$category.url}">
      <img src="{$category.image.medium.url}" alt="{$category.image.legend}">
    </a>

    <h1 class="h2">
      <a href="{$category.url}">{$category.name}</a>
    </h1>

    <div class="category-description">{$category.description nofilter}</div>
  </section>
{/block}
```

I want to add more data to the `$category` array, to display it in my custom shop. This data comes from a custom module.

So for example:

```
    <h1 class="h2">
      <a href="{$category.url}">
          {$category.name} (from {$category.lowest_price} to {$category.highest_price} )
      </a>
    </h1>
```

What's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to add a module, and use a hook.

Otherwise, you must override the category class, in order to add information to the category table.

Regards

Comment: So I would basically replace the entire category template simply with my custom hook...  Seems very inefficient but effective. The PS core classes will load all kinds of data to be used in the actual template, but it will never be displayed, and instead I load all this data *again* in my custom hook.

Comment: Your Hook would allow you to either load normal content or personalized content. At the tpl level, your hook should only intervene on the variable and custom part.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is:

1. Create a new module
2. Install a custom hook
3. Call the custom hook in the .tpl to be modified
4. pass along the parameters of the data that's needed
5. Fetch that data in the custom hook function, add to it as desired
6. Then load a custom tpl file instead

***Details:***

**Install a custom hook**

Add this code to the install function of the main module file `modules/my_module/my_module.php`

```
$custom_hook_name = 'displayMyContent';
$new_hook = new Hook();
$new_hook->name = pSQL($custom_hook_name);
$new_hook->title = pSQL($custom_hook_name);
$new_hook->add();
```

**Call that hook in the .tpl and pass parameters**

```
{hook h='displayMyContent' category=$category}
```

This is the code we need to add to the original .tpl file that we wanted to modify (`themes/my_theme/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/Category.tpl`). It may be required to replace the entire code in that file altogether.

**Fetch that data in the custom hook function**

Go back to `modules/my_module/my_module.php` and create this function in the module:

```
public function hookDisplayMyContent($params){      

    $category = $params['category']; //this is the parameter we passed in the .tpl file

    //do desired data modifications here
    $category['lowest_price'] = 0;
    $category['highest_price'] = 9000;

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'category' => $category
    ));

    return $this->display(dirname(__FILE__), 'views/templates/hook/category.tpl');
    //I have no idea why the display method has 2 parameters, but let's roll with it...
}
```

**Load a custom tpl file**

Finally, we can do whatever we want to do in our custom .tpl file `modules/my_module/views/templates/hook/category.tpl`.

For example:

```
<h1 class="h2">
  <a href="{$category.url}">
      {$category.name} (from {$category.lowest_price} to {$category.highest_price} )
  </a>
</h1>
```

Again, it may be required to copy all the contents of the original .tpl file in here, depending on what modifications you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps cleaner and simpler method is to use the hook

`hookDisplayOverrideTemplate`

You can then add any template vars

```
public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params){

    if($params['controller']->php_self == 'category'){
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'category_lowest_price' => 0,
            'category_highest_price' => 9000,
        ));
    }
}
```

and then the desired variables will be available for use in that template.

However, this only works with **ThirtyBees**, a PrestaShop 1.6 fork